# How to copy Gdk.image?

Tags: graphics, gtk, ocaml, gdk

Is it possible to make a copy of Gdk.image object using lablgtk2 for Ocaml?
I tried to find 'copy' or 'clone' methods but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use pixbuf? It can be created from any drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my clumsy workaround:

```
let copy_image image =

    let w, h = Image.width image, Image.height image in 

    let copy = Image.create ~kind: `FASTEST ~visual: (Image.get_visual image) 

        ~width: w 

        ~height: h in

    for x = 0 to w-1 do

        for y = 0 to h-1 do

            Image.put_pixel copy ~x:x ~y:y (Image.get_pixel image ~x:x ~y:y)

        done

    done;
    copy
```

Comment: although pixbuf variant is also clumsy :(